# Kubernetes - Running load balancer in HA and using DNS to access application

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, haproxy

I am having load balancer (LB) running as [pod](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/service-loadbalancer) on three hosts (node-A, node-B and node-C) in Kubernetes. The LB is being used by GitLab service which is running on port 80. GitLab is running on node-C and i'm able to access it using public IP of node-B. node-B is where i initially setup load balancer (HAProxy) using Replication Controller.

Snippet here:

```
[root@cent-gluster-workstation service-loadbalancer]# cat rc.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: service-loadbalancer
  labels:
    app: service-loadbalancer
    version: v1
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    app: service-loadbalancer
    version: v1
```

Complete detail is present [here](https://pastebin.com/DvMqSUh9)

Here are the issues:
1) I cannot access GitLab using any other node's public IP. Is this expected? If LB is running on all three nodes, then shouldn't the GitLab app be accessible using any node's public IP on port 80?

2) I would like to configure the LBs in a way that i could access them using a 'single' DNS name, for example, gitlab.test.com. I am wondering how this can be done. Will the DNS be mapped to service somehow (and if yes, how?) or to the pods that the service manages?

I am using Google Cloud right now for testing but i am looking for a way which is not cloud-provider specific as the actual setup will be running in-house on VMs. Best would be if i could get my current HAProxy (or NGinx if HAProxy is not feasible) work.

Any help will really be appreciated.

Comment: Did you use NodePort to expose the service? Usually this is cloud service provided dependent, you assign a LB to the service which is then load balanced automatically. And you access the app using the LB ip and not the node IP

Comment: No. I am using LoadBalancer to expose the GitLab service. You can refer the details [here](https://pastebin.com/DvMqSUh9). In my case, we cannot use cloud provider although i am testing on Google Cloud. I am not using any method which cannot be implemented on VMs running in-house.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are not using your haproxy cluster to reach your gitlab instance, but you are reaching gitlab directly.

Let's assume your haproxy is configured correctly, you need to expose it using a service of type Load balancer, exactly as you did with gitlab. You need then to turn the gitlab service into a `NodePort` because you don't need to expose it to the internet with a load balancer (haproxy will be exposed and proxy the request). Finally, please be aware that you need to use the loadbalancer IP address to reach your instance, not your node addresses.
To get the IP simply run `kubectl get svc`.

As a sidenote, since I guess you want to have one instance of haproxy running in every node of your cluster, you could use a `DaemonSet` instead of a ReplicationController which is intended for this exact scope.

Comment: Thanks for the daemonset thing. I have configured GitLab service to use NodePort but i'm not sure how do i configure the daemonset _port_ for LB so that it can listen to GitLab service? I have the config detailed [here](https://pastebin.com/hiSK34CU). I am yet to create a service for LB but before that i wanted to be sure that at least the daemonset is configured correctly.

Comment: In the `spec` section, inside the haproxy container, just add a "ports" key with an array of `containerPort` values such as: "        - containerPort: 80"

Comment: Ok. That's already there in the [link](https://pastebin.com/hiSK34CU) i shared but from this i understand that LB will listen on 80 for any request. How will LB know that it has to forward the request to GitLab service? GitLab is listening on nodePort 30080. This is what is confusing me. I also have `hostPort: 30080` in daemonset config. Is that how it will know?

Comment: Sorry I want' clear exposing my idea. LoadBalancer is an azure feature, you don't need to run a pod for that. The Idea is to have a thing like this: [internet] <-> [azure load balancer through k8s service of type LoadBalancer] <-> [haproxy daemonset] <-> [gitlab service of type nodeport] <-> [gitlab pod]

Comment: I am not using any cloud provider because actual implementation isn't going to use that. We will be setting up infra in-house. :( Any suggestion to get a similar setup in-house where i can have `LBs running in cluster as pods` and accessing the service using DNS?

Comment: That changes the whole thing, then. You need to expose your haproxy on the host networking itself. You can either run the pod with hostNetwork: true or set the hostPort setting in the ports definition. Take a look here: http://alesnosek.com/blog/2017/02/14/accessing-kubernetes-pods-from-outside-of-the-cluster/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154202/discussion-between-technext-and-whites11).

Comment: If i am using `type:LoadBalancer` for GitLab service, then i see that Kubernetes automatically sets up a LoadBalancer on some host with some IP. If for a moment, i forget about LB in HA and want to use a single LB, then even in that case, i see a problem. If LB is running on node A with some VIP and if it goes down, a new one might spawn up on different host, say Node B with a different VIP. How can i map DNS in such case where VIP of LB will keep changing?